# Compound expressions with operators AND/OR

Tags: python

Surprisingly, I can't google how to calculate the chain from *AND* and *OR*:

```
a='a'
b='b'
c='c'
print(a and b or false and c)
```

The result will be **b**, but why?
I thought it could be solved like this:

```
a and b -> b    #last true value, the value is used for the next operation
b or false -> b #first true operand
b and c -> c    #last true value
```

but it's not.

Comment: `and` has higher precedence than `or` - Does `(a and b) or (False and c)` make it clearer?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 2):

and operator has higher precendence than or so it would be evaluated this way :

```
(a and b) or (false and c)
=> b or false
=> b
```